# App crashes on load on adding FirebaseMessaging pod with react-native-webengage

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, webengage

App is crashing on load on adding FirebaseMessaging for iOS.
React-native version: 0.60.4

To reproduce from ExampleApp present in https://github.com/WebEngage/react-native-webengage:

1. Add FirebaseMessaging in Podfile:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

2. Add the following lines in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <Firebase.h>


  [FIRApp configure];
```

3. Run the react-native app for ios after updating pod:

```
pod install 
react-native run-ios
```

Monitor react-native log-ios to get this error

```
Sep 11 12:21:20 go-mac-darshita ExampleApp[58400] <Error>: assertion failed: 18F203 16E226: libxpc.dylib + 80700 [B558DAD6-9E08-3208-B352-1CA4137B67C8]: 0x7d
Sep 11 12:21:20 go-mac-darshita Unknown[58400] <Error>: 
Sep 11 12:21:20 go-mac-darshita com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.9DF1B234-3BCE-4F5A-B29E-04CB9F347D8A[57091] (UIKitApplication:com.webengage.reactnative[0xaed8][57116][58400]) <Notice>: Service exited due to SIGABRT
Sep 11 12:21:22 go-mac-darshita com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.9DF1B234-3BCE-4F5A-B29E-04CB9F347D8A[57091] (com.apple.securityuploadd) <Notice>: Service only ran for 5 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 5 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement the Steps as mentioned in [Disable Swizzling section](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/ios-advanced#section-7-disable-swizzling) of WebEngage docs.